# How to move contacts from one group to another?

Tags: iphone

i have three emails addresses in my Iphone and need to delete one of them. i need to move the contacts that have been added to that account to another one. how can i do that?

Comment: Probably just manually editing is your best bet... You can of course use copy and paste also.

Answer (score 1):

Add the same accounts to you Mac and make sure you have the "Contact" selection **checked** for each account.

This will sync all your contacts in the **Contacts** app for each email account. Open the **Contacts** app and you will be able to see each individual email account (on the left side) and its associated contacts.

Click on the account you wish to transfer **from**. Drag-and-drop desired contacts from one email account to the other. This effectively transfers your contacts to the account you want. Deleting and adding to old and new email accounts respectively.

As far as I know, there is no way to do this in iOS.